# CMake: How can I add a search path for include() from the environment?

Tags: cmake, build-system

I try to create a collection of CMake scripts that are supposed to provide some useful macros and functions for our group of developers and all the projects we're working on. These scripts should be rolled out to all development machines (Win10 & Centos Linux) and the top-level CMakeLists.txt of the projects can include this collection.

From what I read from the CMake docs, [`include()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html) is what should be used to import these scripts. But, of course, CMake doesn't know about the location on the file system. The documentation points to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, but I couldn't figure out a way to set it from "outside" on a global scope, e.g. an environment variable or a CMake configuration value. Setting it from within a project's CMake file would drop portability, as especially on Windows users potentially could choose the install directory of the scripts.

I also don't want to deploy the script collection into CMake's installation directory. Although it would work, it feels dirty to mix up my own scripts with the ones from the CMake distribution.

I could use `find_package()` instead and also provide a package config file and use the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` environment variable. But from my understanding of the docu this is meant to be for build dependencies, e.g. libraries.

I also found questions similar to mine here and in other places, but they usually were about importing external projects for building the own one ( -> `find_package()`). And, of course, about *include* directories for the compilation process. If I just didn't found the proper question & answer, please point me there.

So, what is the best/proper way to make CMake aware of my script collection? Preferably in a way that just a call to `include()` is required in a project's CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I couldn't figure out a way to set it from "outside" on a global scope, e.g. an environment variable or a CMake configuration value.

Just `cmake -D CMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/some/path`. Works for me:

```
$ cd /tmp; echo "include(ulumulu)" > CMakeLists.txt ; strace -e trace=file cmake -D CMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/some/path . |& grep access | grep ulumulu
access("/some/path/ulumulu.cmake", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/ulumulu.cmake", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/tmp/ulumulu", R_OK)            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

> How can I add a search path for include() from the environment?

I would setup my own logic. As simplest as `include($ENV{SEARCH_IN_THIS_PATH})`, but way better would be with `cmake -D PATH_TO_MY_LIBRARY=some_path` and then `include(${PATH_TO_MY_LIBRARY})`.

> I could use find_package() instead and also provide a package config file and use the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH environment variable. But from my understanding of the docu this is meant to be for build dependencies, e.g. libraries.

And module mode `find_package( ... MODULE)` is for finding modules. I would use it. And I would use it also not for libraries.

> what is the best/proper way to make CMake aware of my script collection?

Install your script at `/usr/share/cmake/` path on linux and I think `c:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake` on windows (I have no experience in windows) and use `find_package(the_library MODULE)`.

If not, I recommend just use `find_package` anyway and install your `Find*.cmake` file to `<prefix>/<name>/cmake/`.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'm still a bit undecided between dropping my scripts into CMake's module dir or including them from a path through an environment variable. But one of this is going to be my solution.

Comment: You can also do `find_package( ... HINTS /the/path)`. I recently worked with Zephyr, take a look at how their solved it: https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/guides/zephyr_cmake_package.html : `find_package(Zephyr REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE})`. `find_package` looks like _the way_ of including stuff - there's also version checking you can do, and such. `include()` is for simple files.

Comment: Yes, I found this `HINTS` parameter already in the docs. I think I should upgrade my collection of simple files (therefor `include()`) to a package :)